# Inline variable template

Tags: angularjs

I have the following html in an angular controller

```
<div ng-include="'Module.' + entry.Module.View + '.template'"></div>
```

The value of `entry.Module.View` is "TextField". 
Inside the same controller this script tag exists:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="Module.TextField.template">
    <label>{{entry.Label}}</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="entry.Value">
</script>
```

The problem is that this tries to load the template from an external source. Is there another tag or method better suited to load an inline script template from a variable?

Comment: Is the script tag placed inside the angular app(i.e inside ng-app) ?

Comment: @bhanu.cs Yes, it's in the same controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable in controller and use [`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) as an `element` instead of `attribute`.

```
<ng-include src="moduleUrl"></ng-include>
```

And in controller, you have something like (or if you use `vm`, change it accordingly)

```
$scope.moduleUrl = 'Module.' + $scope.entry.Module.View + '.template';
```

Comment: @JensB glad I could help! :)